# show jQuery textarea on checkbox tick

Tags: jquery, html

I am at a loose end as to why my code is not hiding when i untick. I would be grateful if someone could check my code and point out where I am going wrong. I have posted code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8k8VW/). many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can juse use `this.checked`

```
$('input[name=messagetick]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.contactmessage').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.contactmessage').hide();
    }
});
```

A slightly better version would use `.toggle([showOrHide])`

```
$('input[name="messagetick"]').click(function() {
    $('.contactmessage').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

*Side note*, don't forget your `"` when using an attribute selector.

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/8k8VW/13/)**

Comment: one more thing mark. with this code, how do i now retrieve the value of the textarea box to pass to php?

Comment: Was in the middle of adding `toggle()` `:)`

Comment: i have placed the fiddle code in my code and it is not working. can someone check and tell me what the error is. http://jsfiddle.net/RF5PK/ thanks

Comment: @bollo, the `.click()` should be in the `.ready()` http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/RF5PK/1/

Comment: @bollo, Open another question as it could be a bit more involved then calling `.val()`

Comment: of note - this method will not display the text area if the checkbox is 'checked' at page load. You'll need separate code for this.

Comment: you should use change so you can make the fuctionality for when the user unchecks the checkbox

Answer (score 2):

You can use is(":checked") to see if the checkbox is checked.

Try this:

```
$('input[name=messagetick]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.contactmessage').show();     }
    else {
      $('.contactmessage').hide();
    } });
```

Example @ http://jsfiddle.net/8k8VW/18/

<del>You have selected mootools as the JS framework.   
Change it to jQuery.  

Updated code @ [http://jsfiddle.net/8k8VW/1/][2]</del>

Comment: sorry, just updated question. the issue was why when i untick the box does hide. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You didn't choose jquery as framework and so mootools was loaded.

use this code:

```
$('input[name=messagetick]').click(function() {
      $('.contactmessage').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));     
 });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8k8VW/9/