# Unhiding Row using jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, row

http://jsfiddle.net/PF8nL/1/

Using the code in the above jsfiddle I am unable to unhide and hide a row using jQuery. According to this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6625835/1044984) answer it seems I am doing this correctly.

Do I have some stupid error? possibly causing this?

Code:

```
$('input[name="custom_rejection_option"]').click(function() {
    $('.custom_reject_area').toggle(this.checked);
}};
```

Comment: You're last bracket `}` should be a parenthesis `)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you could say it is off topic, though I initially thought it was something greater.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no close-reason more appropriate for silly mistakes like this, off-topic is the best approximation. BTW, why didn't the error in the Javascript console clue you in to the problem?

Comment: @Barmar The fiddle had the mistake. The live site I am testing on did not have this issue, and therefore did not have this error. The fiddle now works, but site doesn't, which proves that this is more then a syntax issue, though that was still a problem. But yes, this question was not about that.

Comment: If you edit the question with the actual code, you could request that it be reopened.

Comment: @Barmar No thanks. I'd rather close this now, or even delete it. The other error I mentioned I have fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You had a syntax error](http://jsfiddle.net/PF8nL/4/)

```
$('input[name="custom_rejection_option"]').click(function () {
    $('.custom_reject_area').toggle(this.checked);

});
//You had `}` instead of the closing `)`
```

Comment: I missed that ... good catch

Comment: Wow, embarrassing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It Happens. The first place I would see is the browser's console for any obvious syntax errors. If this was useful, Please do mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You just had some typos and things.

```
$('input[name=custom_rejection_option]').click(function() {
    $('.custom_reject_area').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PF8nL/5/